# Coordinate-free Calculus of Variations?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Lately I've been doing a lot of work related to solving variational problems (in the context of surface theory), and I'm getting really tired of going to local coordinates for everything.

So, I was wondering: does anyone know a good coordinate-free treatment for the calculus of variations?  I've heard such literature exists, but I can't say I'm familiar with it.

Any suggested reading you all may have would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Which books uses local coordinates for everything? Jost?

Comment: Willmore and Gelfand/Fomin are also pretty heavy on coordinates IMO.  I also had a tough time reading Lovelock and Rund for the same reason.

Comment: Did you try Struwe's Variational method? It seems that they do not have a lot of coordinate calculations.

Comment: I'll take a look at it -- thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else is curious, I've been getting some mileage out of *Differential Geometry and the Calculus of Variations* by Robert Hermann.

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's quite good, and I'm excited to apply some of the techniques in "Part 2" of the book.